# Tensorflow wrong ouput in print

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have started learning tensorflow ,
Tried to execute a code and continously getting wrong result

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Immutable constants
a = tf.constant(6,name='constant_a')
b = tf.constant(3,name='contant_b')
c = tf.constant(10,name='contant_c')
d = tf.constant(5,name='contant_d')

mul = tf.multiply(a,b,name='mul')
div = tf.div(c,d,name="div")
# Output of the multiplication what needs to be added
addn = tf.add_n([mul,div],name="addn")
# Print out the result
print (addn)
```

Result is just

```
 Tensor("addn:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Strange output wanted the value of addn after it has performed all the computation

Comment: You need to instantiate a session: `sess = tf.Session()` and then `sess.run(addn)` to actually run the computation.

Comment: strange behaviour

Comment: Welcome to Tensorflow :P The separation between graph-building and execution is kind-of a key concept you'll need to grasp. It's easier than it sounds though. Have a look at the Tensorflow's website for tutorials (but don't stop at the easy ones that show you only how to use pre-made code)

Comment: what is this -1 ?

Comment: which ever book you are reading if you would have kept patience and went through , you might have got answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is

```
print (addn)
```

Printing data just gives the name of the

```
 Tensor("addn:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Tensor ,shape and its data type

doesn't give  value it hold any point of time.
This is because above code is not run/executed.
It has just constructed the Graph in tensorflow but haven't executed to get the result To Execute it `session` is required

you can just add few lines ,create a session then print

```
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(addn))
```

**output**
   you will get output 20

> a*b + c/d = 6*3 + 10/5 = 18 + 2 = 20

Complete Code

```
d = tf.constant(5,name='contant_d')

mul = tf.multiply(a,b,name='mul')
div = tf.div(c,d,name="div")

# Output of the multiplication what needs to be added
addn = tf.add_n([mul,div],name="addn")
print (addn)

"""
Printing data just gives the name of the Tensor ,shape and its data type
doesn't give  value it hold anypoint of time
This is because above code is not run
It has just constructed the Graph in tensorflow but haven't executed to get the result
To Execute it session is required  
"""
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(addn))
```